# nginx 502 bad gateway for 1 minute after restart

Tags: server, php, nginx

Everything worked fine until I update PHP to 7.2

For a minute after server reboot nginx throws 502 error.

Nginx error log says if listening to `unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock`:

```
[crit] 671#671: *2 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 123.123.123.123, server: mysite.domain, request: "POST /provider.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "mysite.domain", referrer: "http://mysite.domain/"
```

and says

```
[error] 667#667: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 123.123.123.123, server: mysite.domain, request: "POST /provider.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mysite.domain", referrer: "http://mysite.domain/"
```

if listening to `127.0.0.1:9000`

Anyway one minute later nginx starts working as expected.

Seems like php7.2-fpm starting too slow.

Does somebody know what happend with it? Service should restart in seconds, not minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I think and executed you site  and the page displayed the 502 bad gateway message. This helped me:

```
 - Edit /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
 - Change listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock to listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
 - Ensure the location is set properly in nginx.conf.

location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
 - Run sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

So maybe it will help you.

Link Source: https://wildlyinaccurate.com/solving-502-bad-gateway-with-nginx-php-fpm/